# Gerar JSON a partir de um form com nomes iguais

Tags: php, json

Tenho a seguinte lista de inputs em um form:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como pode se notar, cada linha tem inputs com **name** estático('idrequisicao', 'idmaterial', etc)

```
<form method='POST' id='envia_dados' action='teste_post.php'>";

    foreach ($json as $key => $value) {
        $qtd_format = number_format($value->quantidade, 3, '.', '');

        echo "
            <tr>

                <td><input type=          'text'
                            name=         'idrequisicao'
                            class=        'idrequisicao'
                            readonly=     'readonly'
                            tabindex=     '-1'
                            value=        '$value->item'>
                </td>

                <td><input type=          'text'
                            name=         'idmaterial'
                            class=        'idmaterial'
                            readonly=     'readonly'
                            tabindex=     '-1'
                            value=        '$value->idmaterial'>
                </td>

                <td><input type=          'text'
                            name=         'descmaterial'
                            class=        'descmaterial'
                            readonly=     'readonly'
                            tabindex=     '-1'
                            value=        '$value->descmaterial'>
                </td>

                <td><input type=          'text'
                            name=         'quantidade'
                            class=        'quantidade'
                            id=           'quantidade-$n'
                            readonly=     'readonly'
                            tabindex=     '-1'
                            value=        '$qtd_format'>
                </td>

                <td><input type=          'number'
                            step=         '0.0001'
                            placeholder=  '0,0000'
                            name=         'valunit'
                            class=        'valores'                     
                            id_registro=  '$n'
                            tabindex=     '1'>
                </td>

                <td><input type=          'number'
                            step=         '0.01'
                            placeholder=  '0,00'
                            min=          '0'
                            max=          '100'
                            name=         'icms'
                            class=        'icms'
                            id=           'icms$n'
                            id_registro=  '$n'
                            tabindex=     '1'>
                </td>

                <td><input type=          'number'
                            step=         '0.01'
                            placeholder=  '0,00'
                            min=          '0'
                            max=          '100'
                            name=         'ipi'
                            class=        'ipi'
                            id=           'ipi$n'
                            id_registro=  '$n'
                            tabindex=     '1'>
                </td>

                <td><input type=          'text'
                            name=         'total'
                            class=        'total'
                            id=           'total-$n'
                            tabindex=     '-1'
                            readonly=     'readonly'>
                </td>

                <td>
                    <p class=             'abre_observacao'
                             id=          'idobservacao$n'
                             id_registro= '$n'
                             tabindex=     '-1'>
                    </p>
                </td>

            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td colspan='7'>
                    <textarea
                        name=             'observacao'
                        class=            'observacao'
                        id=               'text_observacao$n'
                        id_registro=      '$n'
                        tabindex=         '-1'
                        placeholder=      'Digite aqui a sua observação...'></textarea>
                </td>
            </tr>
        ";      
        $n += 1;
    }
    echo "</table>";
```

Gostaria de gerar um arquivo JSON, para que possa ser aberto nesta mesma tela mas quando envio todos estes parametros no form, só consigo obeter a ultima linha:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Utilizando o seginte código para visualizar este conteúdo:

```
<?php
$n = 0;
$m = 0;

foreach($_POST as $query_string_variable => $value) {
    if ($n == $m + 9) {
        echo "-------------------------------------<br/>";
        $m += 9;
    }

    echo "$query_string_variable  = $value <br/>";
    
    $n++;
}
?>
```

Tentei gerar desta maneira:

```
$dados = $_POST;
$dados_json = json_encode($dados, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
$path = "_js/_json/_requisicoes/";
$diretorio = dir($path);
$encontrado = 0;
while ($arquivo = $diretorio -> read()) {
    if ($idreq["id_req"] . "_r" . ".json" == $arquivo)  {
        $encontrado = 1;
    }
    //echo $arquivo;
}
if ($encontrado == 1) {
    echo "<br/><h1>O arquivo já existe!</h1><br/>l";
} else {
    $diretorio -> close();
    $fp = fopen("_js/_json/_requisicoes/" . $idreq["id_req"] . "_r" . ".json", "a");
    $jswrite = fwrite($fp, $dados_json);   
    fclose($fp);
}
```

Mas continua gerando o json com apenas a ultima linha:

```
    {"idrequisicao":"026","idmaterial":"00.000.0057","descmaterial":"Material teste
 58","quantidade":"921.995","valunit":"8","icms":"8","ipi":"8","total":"","observacao":""}
```

Estou tentando obter um json igual a este:

```
[{"item":"001","idmaterial":"00.000.0011","descmaterial":"Material teste
 17","quantidade":"1500"},
{"item":"002","idmaterial":"00.000.0042","descmaterial":"Material teste 
20","quantidade":"650.620"},
{"item":"003","idmaterial":"00.000.0039","descmaterial":"Material teste 
31","quantidade":"500.969"}]
```

Se alguém puder dar alguma luz. Obrigaduuu!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Transforme os names para o formato de array, o total por exemplo ficaria assim: `total[]`. Assim você terá todos os dados no post.

Comment: Sucesso, deu certo. Muito obrigado!

Answer (score -1):

Transformando o que há de nome para array facilita e assim terá todas as informações necessárias.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta!